# How to use loops in JasperReports .jrxml file?

Tags: loops, for-loop, jasper-reports

I am using iReport Designer to design the .jrxml file.

How can I use the *for* loop or *if* loop in .jrxml file?
Is it possible?
If yes how?

Comment: You can use ternary operator `? :`. And you cannot use `for` loop and `if` statement. BTW, why you need loop?

Comment: I need it for Generating the Adhoc Reports using jasper.From UI client vl select the fields whatever he wants and he vl click on Generate Report.Then it should display the report only with those fields.For this i want to pass the Fields combination as a parameter to the jrxml file and there i want to loop through the fields.Otherwise is there any other way to generate the Adhoc Reports.If yes you can share it to me it vl help alot to me.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use a scriptlet. It's basically a Java class that extends either of the following two classes:

- [`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractScriptlet`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRAbstractScriptlet.html)
- [`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDefaultScriptlet.html)

In a scriptlet, you can indicate that a certain piece of code should be executed every time a report event occurs, e.g., report, page, or column initialization.

In a scriptlet, you may use loops. You may access fields, parameters, and variable values. You may also adjust variable values.

There is a chapter on scriptlets in the [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/system/files/documentation/jasperreports-ultimate-guide-3v2.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is create a list of selected fields(which client UI selects) and pass it as a collection to JasperFillManager.fillReport and in the jrxml create a field names _THIS which will represent the value's in the List.
And as you want those field to printed in loop, place them in the detail band of the report.